# Weird response JAX-RS when producing XML

Tags: java, xml, jax-rs

I've currently having some problems unmarshalling XML that I marshalled myself. It took me some time to figure it out, because I thought the marshalling went nicely (no exceptions etc.). The method that produces my XML returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" 
    <TestClass> 
        <testValue>banaan</testValue> 
    </TestClass>
```

But suddenly I had the very obvious realization (much too late), that the XML produced isn't correct at all. It should obviously be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
    <TestClass> 
        <testValue>banaan</testValue> 
    </TestClass>
```

How is it possible that this very simple code:

```
@Path("test")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public TestClass getTestClass() {
    TestClass test = new TestClass();
    test.setTestValue("banaan");
    return test;
}
```

And the TestClass:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "TestClass")
public class TestClass {

private String testValue;   

@XmlElement(name = "testValue")
public String getTestValue() {
    return testValue;
}

public void setTestValue(String testValue) {
    this.testValue = testValue;
}

public TestClass() {

}
```

}

produces invalid XML? And more importantly, how can I fix it?

Comment: Which version of Glassfish are you using? Are you using XJC to generate TestClass from an XSD or did you add the annotations yourself? Are you adding any external libraries to the classpath?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean by XJC and XSD. I'm probably doing the simplest thing possible. The TestClass is just a simple class that I created for this purpose and I did indeed annotate it (see the updated question for the code of the TestClass).

I did have other libraries added to the project at one point, but I deleted them some time ago.

Comment: And I'm using Glassfish server 4.

Comment: I am assuming that you are using the new application class to discover the Jersey class then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the default attempt to create a JAXBContext which should function correctly, however it seems to be messing up somehow. Try adding a custom context resolver to your application.

```
@Provider
public class XmlContextProvider implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {
    private JAXBContext context = null;

    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> type) {
        if (type != TestClass.class) {
            return null; // we don't support nothing else than TestClass
        }

        if (context == null) {
            try {
                context = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestClass.class);
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return context;
    }
}
```

You will also have to add XmlContextProvider to your Application class.

Comment: I tried it, but it still produces the same XML. By Application class, do you mean ApplicationConfig? Because I can't seem to find an Application class. Furthermore, NetBeans automatically added the XmlContentProvider to ApplicationConfig like this: `resources.add(HelloWorldResource.XmlContextProvider.class);`

Comment: I haven't used NetBeans' J2EE development features so I don't know how it does the application management. My guess is that the ApplicationConfig class is the correct application class referred to by your web.xml and extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application. Try adding a println to the getContext method and check your logs to ensure that it is being called.

Comment: How are you testing your web service? Browser? If so, right click and view source so that you can see the raw data being returned by the server. I suggest using the Chrome plugin Postman for testing ReST services.

Comment: NetBeans has it's own test suite for REST applications and I'm using that to input and receive the requests. Which getContext method are you referring to?

Comment: The one in XmlContextProvider. Try using postman to test your responses. It could be that the response is fine but the netbeans GUI is screwing it up.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was indeed the NetBeans Test Suite screwing up somewhere. Damnit I hate such stupid problems....

Answer (score 0):

How are you marshalling the code? It seems like you are setting the class and its values properly, but it may be an issue with how you are creating the marshall object and the context/formatted output you are using

Here is an example
 `JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestClass.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        m.marshal(test, stringWriter);
        return stringWriter.toString();`

Did you do something along these lines?

Comment: Well, I'm using Netbeans and the RESTful Web Services plugin, which includes Jersey, together with Glassfish server. I'm simply following the Jersey documentation, which included the example that I'm using now. I'm guessing the marshalling and unmarshalling is all done by Jersey, so I'm not quite sure how it is marshalling.

PS: Please excuse me if I answered your question incorrectly or using the wrong terms, I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: I know I can simply get the body of the POST request and treat it like  a String and then marshall it myself. But 1 of the nice things I read about in the documentation is that Jersey can do it all automatically.